# Python: add column to dataframe that relates to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported a stock's data from yahoo into a dataframe using pandas_datareader.
There are 2 columns : date and the adjusted close of the stock.

```
Date        Adj Close          
2017-08-31  168.851196
2017-09-01  169.867691
2017-09-05  165.333496
2017-09-06  165.233810
2017-09-07  166.001160
2017-09-08  163.121201
2017-09-11  168.412735
2017-09-12  169.020630
2017-09-13  169.777969
2017-09-14  168.811356
2017-09-15  179.484131
2017-09-18  186.898300
2017-09-19  186.698990
2017-09-20  185.194214
2017-09-21  180.131882
2017-09-22  178.377991
2017-09-25  170.405807
2017-09-26  171.362473
2017-09-27  175.119354
2017-09-28  175.069534
2017-09-29  178.148788
2017-10-02  178.377991
2017-10-03  178.746704
2017-10-04  180.241486
2017-10-05  180.141861
2017-10-06  180.670013
2017-10-09  184.745804
2017-10-10  188.273499
2017-10-11  190.276505
2017-10-12  190.366211
```

I want to be able to insert another column called 'Log return' which takes the Adj Close of the current day (the dates aren't all 1 day apart because of trading days) and divide it by the previous days Adj Close and then *take the natural logarithm of that quotient*

I.e. Ln(A(today)/A(yesterday)), where A is just the adj close.

By the way, my dataframe variable is called df.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

#import datetime internal datetime module
#datetime is a Python module
import datetime

#datetime.datetime is a data type within the datetime module
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)

#DataReader method name is case sensitive
df = web.DataReader("nvda", 'yahoo', start, end)

#invoke to_csv for df dataframe object from 
#DataReader method in the pandas_datareader library

#..\first_yahoo_prices_to_csv_demo.csv must not
#be open in another app, such as Excel

df = df.iloc[0:, 5:]  #Trims the set to Adj Close
```

That is what I have so far in my code.
**EDIT** I do not want A(today)/A(yesterday)-1, I actually need Ln(A(today)/A(yesterday)). (natural logarithm)

Comment: So you just don't want to use your formula on the previous rows but only on the previous day?

Comment: How do you want to handle the missing days in the calculation?

Comment: What is expected output first 5 rows?

Comment: I dont need to handle the missing days. Trading days arent 7 days a week.

Comment: So you just want to divide by previous closest day, if yesterday is missing.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I actually want to take the natural logarithm of, (today's adj close) divided by (yesterdays adj close)

Comment: @crazyGamer Yes, that is, the previous trading day. (All of which are included in the dataframe)

Comment: Okay, got it. Have added an answer with `ln`.

Comment: @Simplex1 - So need `df['Log Return'] = df['Adj Close'].pct_change()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Adj Yesterday'] = df['Adj Close'].shift()
df['Log Return'] = df['Adj Close'] / df['Adj Yesterday'] - 1.
```

If this is not quite what you wanted, but close, [here is the docs for shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).

You can also use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html), or [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) if missing temporal data.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`Series.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

```
df['Log Return'] = df['Adj Close'].pct_change()
```

If need `ln`:

```
df['Log Return'] = np.log(df['Adj Close'].pct_change())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# First ensure dates are in order
df = df.sort_values('Date')
# Divide all rows by their previous and find log
diff = np.log(df[1:]['Adj Close'] / df[0:-1]['Adj Close'])
# Add new column, first row will be NaN as it has no previous day
df['Log Return'] = pd.concat(pd.Series([pd.nan]), diff)
```

Comment: Perhaps confusingly, [`np.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) is the natural logarithm. `np.log10` is the other one.

Comment: Gets me every time. Thanks.